# Angular source maps sourceMappingUrl broken

Tags: angular, source-maps

I have recently upgraded from Angular 7 to Angular 8 and I noticed that in Chrome and Firefox I have an error in the dev console

Firefox:

> Source map error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
>
> Source Map URL: [url]

Chrome:

> DevTools failed to parse SourceMap
>   https://mydomain/[url]

When I inspect my `main.js` I see the following set for source sourceMappingURL

```
},[[0,"runtime","vendor"]]]);
//# sourceMappingURL=[url]
```

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out where this is supposed to get configured or what has changed. Has anyone encountered this or know of a solution?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the URL mentioned in the error ([https://mydomain/[url]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYm6r.png)), it should open 
   the mentioned chunk(.js.map file). If its not there check the path is correct or not.
2. You can turn off source map files by unchecking this option in chrome console setting. NOTE: This is not an actual fix.

[image]

3. From the firefox error, it looks like it could be a JSON parse issue. Add a stringify method `var yourDataStr = JSON.stringify(yourdata)` before the `Parse()` method, wherever you are validating the JSON.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: yeah I definitely want them enabled; I am more concerned with how this is being constructed incorrectly so I can leave them up. the URL `/[url]` is always invalid - it looks as if it would be attempting to inject something into the path but failed for some reason (this looks like a placeholder, maybe?). The sourceMappingURL should look more like ```},[[0,"runtime","vendor"]]]);
//# sourceMappingURL=main.js.map```